# Rails: Polymorphism, undefined method `primary_key' for String:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I am trying to achieve polymorphic behaviour in my rails application.
I have `3 models`:

- Customer
- Supplier
- Transaction

Transaction has a Party(either customer or supplier).

I have created a model `Party` as `concern` when I am trying to save or update I receive this error.

[image: Error on save]

The models are as follows:

`party.rb`

```
module Party
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :transactions, :as => :party
  end
end
```

`customer.rb`

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  include Party
  ....
end
```

`supplier.rb`

```
class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  include Party
  ....
end
```

`transaction.rb`

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :party, polymorphic: true

  ....
end
```

When hit save the params received at server are

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"....", "transaction"=>{"party"=>"4", ...}, "commit"=>"Update Transaction", "id"=>"2"}
```

Hope someone can figure out the issue. Thanks for your time.

Here is the transactions schemea.

```
create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.string "transaction_type"
    t.integer "supplier_id"
    t.integer "customer_id"
    t.string "party_type", null: false
    t.bigint "party_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["party_type", "party_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_party_type_and_party_id"
  end
```

Comment: Why you using as concern. Follow this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations. Polymorphic table should have objectable_id, object_id column to store. Party table dost not look real database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve Polymorphism using Party you will have to change the code as the following:

1. Create table called "parties" contains resource_id (same as the other models type) and resource_type (String).
2. declare a relation inside your Party model "belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true"
3. Update the Customer and Supplier model to contain "has_many / has_one :party(eis), as: :resource".

Your code treat party as a module which does not implement primary_key method as the activerecord use it to build the associations on create or update.

Answer (score 2):

Can you add transactions table schema in question?
I am assuming that the transactions table has `party_id` and `party_type`.
So if the columns are present then you need check view so that in params controller should receive like `"transaction"=>{"party_id"=>"4", "party_type"=>"custmer"...}`

Comment: I have added schema for transaction.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you exposed here,  this issue is caused by the params sent. You need to make sure that "party_id" holds  the polymorphic resource id and "party_type" either "customer" or "supplier".
Also as you are using rails' polymorphic behaviour, "supplier_id" and "party_id" columns are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with params, it contains "party" => "4", for polymorphic association you can have one of the following:

1. `"transaction"=>{"party_type" => "Customer", "party_id" => "4", ... }`
2. `"transaction"=>{"party" => <Customer OR supplier object>, ... }`

Rails will try `transactioin.party.class.primary_key` to find out primary_key column, in above case it will get `String` for `transaction.party.class` and hence it will raise `NoMethodError (undefined method` primary_key' for String:Class)`.

You can try assigning `transaction.party = "4"` in rails console, you will get same error.